# Is there a ROS simulation for parrot bebop drone 2 using bebop_autonomy?

Tags: ros, simulation, bebop-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Is there a support for running the bebop drone 2 as a simulation on gazebo and ROS using the bebop_autonomy package.
I would like to test my programs before flying in real world.
Also, has anyone added new sensors like a lidar to the bebop drone?

Thanks
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238596/is-there-a-ros-simulation-for-parrot-bebop-drone-2-using-bebop_autonomy?/) by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 654 on 2016-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kathir](https://answers.ros.org/users/28902/kathir/) on 2016-12-27**:
@AlexR : Have you got any support for simulation of bebop drone 2 on gazebo simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on this. Currently, I am figuring out how to start the bebop autonomy driver as a nodelet (I think that this will be more efficient than a node). Then, I think I will be able to communicate with either a real or simulated Parrot Bebop 2. After I have accomplished this, I will post it to a Github repo and share it with you.

---

Originally posted by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) with karma: 32 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2016-07-19**:
Great! this will be really helpful.

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2016-10-06**:
@errolflynn Have you had any progress on this?

**Comment by [Kathir](https://answers.ros.org/users/28902/kathir/) on 2016-12-27**:
@errolflynn Have you simulated Parrot Bebop 2 with Gazebo ? Can you share the packages for simulating the Parrot Bebop ?

**Comment by [Kathir](https://answers.ros.org/users/28902/kathir/) on 2016-12-27**:
@Mani Do you have support for Parrot bebop drone on Gazebo with Ros ?

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2016-12-28**:
@kathir No. I am not working on this. But I know at least one research group is working to provide Gazebo simulation for Parrot Bebop drones. It's not been released yet.

**Comment by [errolflynn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26799/errolflynn/) on 2017-02-02**:
This has been on the backburner for quite some time. I probably will not get to it for a while at least. If anyone else makes progress, feel free to reach out to me to collaborate.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. Most likely I arrived a few years late, but I think it may be useful for future visitors to the page. My colleagues and I, at the University of Sannio in Benevento, Italy, developed a ROS package for simulating the behavior of the Parrot Bebop 2. The ROS package is compatible with both Indigo Igloo and Kinetic Kame distros of ROS. Moreover, we are working to make the code compatible with Parrot Sphinx (it simulates the firmware behavior thus, making it possible to put it in the control loop). Here the link to the repository available on GitHub.

https://github.com/gsilano/BebopS

---

Originally posted by [Giuseppe Silano](https://answers.ros.org/users/44159/giuseppe-silano/) with karma: 21 on 2019-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1